# How to shutdown a Rack app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, sinatra, rack

I want to shutdown a Sinatra app by sending it a HTTP request like:

```
get '/shutdown'
   # need some code here to stop the app
end
```

How can this be down?

Comment: Be careful with this. If your system is accessible from the internet it'd be trivial to find your command. Add some authentication to only allow authorized shutdowns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that this is only running in one process, you can simply terminate the process with `Kernel.exit`. If you want to invoke the Sinatra shutdown handlers, you could try something like `Process.kill("TERM", Process.pid)` to send SIGTERM to the current process.

Answer (score 0):

See [Kernel::exit!](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-exit-21):

```
get '/shutdown' do
  exit!
end
```